# Wordpress: how to override or remove a function of plugin in child theme?

Tags: wordpress

I do researched the related topics.

I would like to override the includes/functions.php in a plugin.
But there is no any `apply_filters` `do_action` and hook, just a `function`.
I don't want to make a direct change in any plugin file.

Is there no way to modify the function in my child theme?
Or can I remove the function & write a new one in my child theme?
Or can I redirect to my new function in child theme?

..\wp-content\plugins\xxx\admin\includes\functions.php

```
function email_footer(){
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="wpc-contact-info" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        ...
    </div>
    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

..\wp-content\plugins\xxx\admin\classes\class-xxx.php

```
function __construct( ){
    $this->mail_footer  = $this->mail_footer();
}
protected function mail_footer(){
    $mail_footer = email_footer();
    return $mail_footer;
}
```

`function email_footer` will need to rewrite/override

Comment: Can you provide the code from the file in question? Can I assume it doesn't have the `function_exists` check wrapped around it? Generally speaking in PHP, if a function gets defined without a namespace you cannot override it.

Comment: hi @PhilF, I added the code in the question already. Thanks.
ya, it doesnt have the function_exits in entire plugin

Comment: you can not redefine a function, it will throw PHP exception. you can only modify the return value or output of already define function only if it has a `do_action` call inside it otherwise there is no way to change the function's behavior without modifying the function itself.

Comment: there is no do_action. Is that able to write code in muplugins?

Comment: What ends up happening with that email footer string. Does it get appended to an email that gets sent out with `wp_mail()`?

Comment: this is part of the email content. yes, this footer string did show in the email footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K, given your code. There is no way to override the `email_footer` function and there are no hooks/filters showing in your code either. One option (depending on your WordPress knowledge) is search the code (ideally through step debugging with something like xDebug) and see if that code eventually runs through some filter before it is sent to the user.

Comment: ok thanks, i get it, I actually found that hook at very top level. I thought there will have a way to override a small function instead of change alot code in that top level's hook.